# Is there any way in .NET, other then Oledb to be database independent

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, data-access-layer

Is there a way my DAL classes can be re used across different databases ?

I know some technologies (Linq and EF) support rapid development, I appreciate this feature but I also want to keep my DAL Code reuse able in different database.

A Simple thing that come to mind is use of Oledb with inline SQL queries, Is there a more elegant way ? please guide me. I am just considering 2 things.

1. support to 4 most commonly used databases (SQL Server, My SQL, Access, Oracle).
2. Rapid development support.

Thanks

Comment: Please edit your question heading, what is whihc?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Keeping an application database agnostic (ADO.NET vs encapsulating DB logic)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3080601/keeping-an-application-database-agnostic-ado-net-vs-encapsulating-db-logic)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entity Framework does the work you want. The most commonly used databases support it, with the exception of Oracle. For Oracle, you have to use third-party components as the official Oracle support for Entity Framework is still in beta.

Comment: does EF support ACCESS and MY SQL as well ? Does it allow bulk insert, transations and bulk edit ?

Comment: There is no support for Access as far as I know. But MySQL is supported via connector/NET.

Answer (score 4):

You may consider using an [ORM framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) such as [Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399572.aspx) or [NHibernate](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/NHibernateForNET). This way your data access layer will be database agnostic.

Comment: Thanks @Darin, does EF support ACCESS and MY SQL as well ? Does it allow bulk insert, transations and bulk edit ?

Answer (score 3):

If you stick to the interfaces ([`IDbConnection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.idbconnection.aspx), [`IDbCommand`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.idbcommand.aspx), ...) and their factory methods ([`IDbConnection.CreateCommand`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.idbconnection.createcommand.aspx)) then the only code that needs to know what database you are using is the initial connection creation (which can be encapsulated).

Comment: Thanks @Richard, but using interfaces will consume more development time and it will not be that rapid. Please advice.

Comment: @user576510 If you want database independence you will need to get everything right and test for all cases you positivey support. Being portable is more complex and resource intensive.

Comment: @user576510: How does de-coupling as much code as you can from the dependency of the database engine "consume more development time"?  The idea behind abstraction through interfaces in this case is to minimize the amount of work that needs to be done in order to support different database engines.